# Assigning a value literal to a struct field of a generic type without running into an IncompatibleAssign error

Tags: go, generics

This is fine:

```
type constraint interface {
    ~float32 | ~float64
}

type foo[T constraint] struct {
    val T
}

func (f *foo[float64]) setValToPi() {
    f.val = 3.14
}
```

However, if I change `constraint` to also include `int` types, I run into an error:

```
type constraint interface {
    ~float32 | ~float64 | ~int
}

type foo[T constraint] struct {
    val T
}

func (f *foo[float64]) setValToPi() {
    f.val = 3.14 // IncompatibleAssign: cannot use 3.14 (untyped float constant) as float64 value in assignment
}
```

Why do constraints that include types that don't belong to the same "type group" cause this error, and how should I deal with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This syntax:

```
func (f *foo[float64]) setValToPi() {
    // ...
}
```

Is simply a method declaration. It does **not instantiate** the generic type `foo`. The identifier `float64` you have within square brackets is the name of the type parameter. It could be `T`, as in the type definition, just as well.

It's like you wrote:

```
type foo[float64 constraint] struct {
    val float64
}
```

Since `float64` is a predeclared identifier, you can shadow it with a type parameter name.

So within the method `setValToPi`, the only known information about the type of `val` is that it is constrained to `constraint`, e.g. the union of `~float32 | ~float64 | ~int`.

If you change the method declaration to:

```
func (f *foo[T]) setValToPi() {
    // ...
}
```

You will get the same error with `T` instead:

> cannot use 3.14 (untyped float constant) as T value in assignment

And the error is given by the fact that `3.14` (an untyped floating-point constant) can't be always assigned to **all** possible instances of `foo[T]`, specifically the one where `T` is indeed `~int`.

Playground with the `float64` identifier as type param: https://gotipplay.golang.org/p/1EuAsSKdihK

A solution would be to make the method accept a value of type parameter type (beside using less confusing identifiers):

```
func (f *foo[T]) SetValue(val T) {
    f.val = val
}
```

This of course means you can't set fixed values like `3.14`, but as explained, this is a mistake in the first place. Other possible solutions are using `any`/`interface{}` as the field type. For some inspiration, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71810399/how-can-i-implement-a-generic-either-type-in-go) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72961749/4108803).