# Can I construct a slice of a generic type with different type parameters?

Tags: go, generics, slice, type-parameter

In the following code I have a token type that contains a literal value. By using an empty interface I can create a slice of tokens and append tokens that have different types. I don't think it's possible to accomplish the same using generics since we wouldn't be able to infer a type for the Slice of tokens. Is this assumption correct?

```
type Token struct {
    TokenType string
    Literal interface{}
}

func main(){
    tok1 := &Token{TokenType: "string", Literal: "foo"}
    tok2 := &Token{TokenType: "integer", Literal: 10}
    tokS := []*Token{tok1, tok2}
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**No.**

Given a parametrized `Token` type as:

```
type Token[T any] struct {
    TokenType string
    Literal   T
}
```

each instantiation with a different type argument produces a different (named) type.

In other words, `Token[string]` **is not** assignable to `Token[int]`. Nor is it assignable to `Token[any]` as `any` here is used as a static type to instantiate `T`.

So when you construct a slice with a specific instance of `Token[T any]`, different instances are simply not assignable to its element type:

```
tokS := []*Token[string]{tok1, tok2}
// invalid: cannot use tok2 (variable of type *Token[int]) as type *Token[string] in array or slice literal
```

The only slice that can hold different types, as `Token[string]` and `Token[int]` is `[]interface{}` or `[]any`.

---

> since we wouldn't be able to infer a type for the Slice of tokens. Is this assumption correct?

Almost. More precisely, the slice of Token wouldn't infer anything because you yourself must construct it with a concrete instantiation of the generic type

Type inference is used to deduce missing type parameters from those already supplied for function arguments. Generic **types** must be explicitly instantiated, with a concrete type argument for each type parameter.

Answer (score -1):

> Is this assumption correct?

Yes. Your can have a slice of `Token[string]` or `Token[int]`.