# Convert func(T) to func(any)

Tags: go, generics

I want to be able to enforce similarity between two fields of a struct but also have several of these structs in a map or slice.

Here's a simplified example of my problem:

```
package main

type foo[T any] struct {
    f func() T
    v T
}

type bar struct {
    x []*foo[any]
}

func baz[T any](b *bar, f func() T) {
    b.x = append(b.x, &foo[any]{f: f})
}

func main() {
    var b bar
    baz(&b, func() int { return 0 })
}
```

The compiler complains

> ./prog.go:13:33: cannot use f (variable of type func() T) as type func() any in struct literal

The funny thing is that this can work if I didn't need to have a function pointer in the struct. See https://go.dev/play/p/qXTmaa9PuVe

So, is there a way for me to turn a T into an any?

I know I could do this with interface{}s and use reflect to enforce what I want, but I'm sure it's possible with only generics.

The context in case there is a way around my problem is that I'm making a flag package. The important structs look like this:

```
type flag[T any] struct {
    value T
    parse func(in string) (T, error)
    // Other fields removed for simplicity...
}

type FlagSet struct {
    // could flag[any] be replaced with a better answer?
    flags map[string]*flag[any]
    // Other fields removed for simplicity...
}
```

The question was closed so I have to put the answer to the second part of my question here

> could flag[any] be replaced with a better answer?

The answer to the above is yes.

Solution:

Originally I though something like: "a `func()` fits a `func()` and an `any` fits a `T` so why can't I have a `func() T` fit a `func() any`?" Of course the reason is a `func() any` is not an `any` and so it cannot hold a `func() T`.

Instead, you can do the following:

```
package main

type foo[T any] struct {
    f func() T
    v T
}

func (f *foo[_]) set() {
    f.v = f.f()
}

type anyfoo interface {
    set()
}

type bar struct {
    x []anyfoo
}

func baz[T any](b *bar, f func() T) {
    b.x = append(b.x, &foo[T]{f: f})
}

func main() {
    var b bar
    baz(&b, func() int { return 0 })
}
```

Comment: I closed this question. Thanks for editing. The edit makes it a little bit clearer, however it is still difficult to assess the validity of your own solution because 1) there isn't enough context about how you plan to use this code beyond merely initializing the struct 2) using an interface still falls into the realm of `[]any`, which is covered by the dupe links. The underlying issue of instantiating `foo` with `any` is also covered in the links. So I don't think there is a compelling reason to reopen

Comment: This question however should stick around as it is a good signpost for the kind of issue you encountered. What I encourage you to do is to make your own solution generally applicable and post it under one of the open questions that you think are closest to your situation, probably [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71247543/can-i-construct-a-slice-of-a-generic-type-with-different-type-parameters)

Comment: I solved my problem. I just wanted it reopened temporarily to move the answer to the official answer area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but also have several of these structs in a map or slice

You cannot do this (in a type safe way). All values of e.g. a slice must have the same element type. If you want to store different ones you have to resort to `interface{}` and type switch later.

If you use the correct technical term parametric polymorphism instead of "generics" which doesn't explain what is going on you will see why func(T) and func(any) are different, unconvertable types.

> So, is there a way for me to turn a T into an any?

No, there was no pre-"generics" way and there is no post-"generics" way. It helps to think of "turn into" as what Go allows: "type conversion" and "assignment". You can assign any variable of type T to a variable of type any.

You might overcome your issue by using an adaptor function (closure):

```
w := func(a any){ f(a.(T)) }
b.x = append(b.x, &foo[any]{w})
```

Comment: It just doesn't make a lot of sense to instantiate `foo` with `any` to begin with. The OP's bar type should be a slice of `[]any`

Comment: @blackgreen I agree. Probably an instance of what a lot of people feared about the introduction of "generics". A plain old Flag interface probably would be good enough.

Comment: IMO a big part of this confusion and instantiating parametrized types with `any` comes from the identifier itself. Newcomers read "any" and mistakenly think it's some magic placeholder, when all it does is hiding the complexity and traps of the empty `interface{}` behind an innocuous word. This concern was raised during discussion of the proposal, and now we see that it does come up frequently.

Comment: I know an any is another name for an interface{} and since everything satisfies an interface{} I thought I could convert something equally general to it. I just thought the syntax was different than what I imagined.