# With Go 1.18 generics, how to use constrained type as argument to function that expects a concrete type?

Tags: go, generics

Go version: 1.18

Here's a silly example that is not particularly useful. I am using this as an exercise to learn generics.

I have a `Pokemon` interface

```
type Pokemon interface {
    ReceiveDamage(float64)
    InflictDamage(Pokemon)
}
```

and `Charmander` with type parameter that implements the `Pokemon` interface.

```
type Float interface {
    float32 | float64
}

type Charmander[F Float] struct {
    Health      F
    AttackPower F
}
```

I want to use `Charmander`'s attack power to inflict damage.

```
func (c *Charmander[float64]) ReceiveDamage(damage float64) {
    c.Health -= damage
}

func (c *Charmander[float64]) InflictDamage(other Pokemon) {
    other.ReceiveDamage(c.AttackPower)
}
```

My compiler gives error

> cannot use c.AttackPower (variable of type float64 constrained by Float) as float64 value in argument to other.ReceiveDamage compiler(IncompatibleAssign)

I already instantiated the struct generic as `*Charmander[float64]`. I'd expect that the compiler knows `AttackPower` is a `float64`.

When I pass a `float64` into a function that expects `float64`, why should it complain? On the other hand, `ReceiveDamage` does not complain. I am subtracting a `float64` from `Health` which is a constrained type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use type conversions. The method `ReceiveDamage` expects a `float64` but the main type is parametrized in `F`. Something of type `F`, even if constrained to floats only, or even if constrained to one specific float, **is not `float64`. It is `F`**. (Moreover, it could also be instantiated with `float32`).

Both conversions compile because `float64` is convertible to all types in the type parameter's type set, `float32` and `float64`, and vice-versa.

So the methods become:

```
func (c *Charmander[T]) ReceiveDamage(damage float64) {
    c.Health -= T(damage)
}

func (c *Charmander[T]) InflictDamage(other Pokemon) {
    other.ReceiveDamage(float64(c.AttackPower))
}
```

Fixed playground: https://go.dev/play/p/FSsdlL8tBLn

Watch out that the conversion `T(damage)` may cause loss of precision when `T` is instantiated with `float32`. (Probably this won't be an issue in this specific use case...)

Comment: Basic question. Using OP's way of implementing the type `c *Charmander[float64]` is again valid but a bad practice? rather than your way of doing it explicitly `c := &Charmander[float64]{40, 5}`?

Comment: @Inian you mean using the name `float64` in the receiver type param? Yes, I think it's a bad practice, because `float64` in that case is just a name, not the type. See also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70380575/assigning-a-value-literal-to-a-struct-field-of-a-generic-type-without-running-in/70381052#70381052